# GWT and MVC type calls

Tags: model-view-controller, gwt

I have a GWT app that when launched it takes you to a page with just a menu.  So as a shortcut type thing I would like the users to be able to go straight to the page they want.  So if the default start page is x, the should be able to say x/add and it will take them to the add page.  How would I get that in gwt?  Do I need a bunch of different entry points?

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this, you should use the URL's "fragment", which is the part after the #.  For example, if your app is at /x, you could have a different UI displayed when someone navigates to /x#add

If you don't want to write this logic yourself, you should look into the [gwt-presenter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/) project, which was written to make MVP apps easier, but also includes an `EventBus` (to publish events to all corners of your app), and a [PlaceManager](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#wp__txAjpOs/trunk/src/main/java/net/customware/gwt/presenter/client/place/PlaceManager.java&q=Place%20package:http://gwt-presenter%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc) to facilitate events being fired when the fragment changes (and to change the fragment at will).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a discussion we already had so I'll just link to [the related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542395/how-to-provide-hyperlink-in-email-pointing-to-a-specific-method-inside-gwt-app-b) Please see the answers and comments there. Basically, it might be advantageous to just interact with the [History](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) class directly, instead of introducing MVP to your project, but YMMV (I'm a huge fan of MVP myself, but it's not for everyone. Besides, I like to know the stuff "under the hood" ;))